# how to animate elements to move in a circular path using CSS

Tags: html, css

I want my element, which is a text, to move in a circular path. I need to use CSS for this. I am attaching my code for the same. The error I face is I need to translate my element to the circumference of the circle. This causes the text to jump to the circumference at the start and the end of the animation. How do I solve this? Is there another method to animate objects to move in a circular direction?

```css
.element{
position:relative;
top:50%;
left:50%;
transform:translate(-50%,-50%); 
animation: orbit2 4s forwards;
}


@-webkit-keyframes orbit2 {
    from {  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(150px) rotate(0deg); }
    to   {  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(150px) rotate(-360deg); }
}
```

```html
<div class= "element">
<a>NEN</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this (or can even change the way the text wraps around the circle):

```css
#spin {
  position:absolute;
  top:25%;
  left:50%;
  margin:50px;
  animation: orbit 4s forwards infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes orbit {
    from {  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(150px) rotate(0deg); }
    to   {  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(150px) rotate(-360deg); }
}
```

```html
<div id="spin"><p>text</p></div>
```

Comment: Nice! Added to my favorites

Comment: hey @granite, thanks for the answer. I have used this method before. The problem I have with this is, you need the to translate the text to the circumference of the circle. This will cause the text to move to a different location at the beginning and end of the animation. Since the iteration count in my cod is 1, this will be problem. Is there a way to move the text from the position it already is?

Comment: To clarify:  So your text is (for example) at the left side of a page and 50% way down from top, you want the circle loop to start exactly right there where that word is on the page, then make a clockwise loop. Yes?  Though I may not figure out how, a clarification may provide another coder so as to find a solution.